# ERROR [TypeError: Network request failed] Expo App

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

I would like to test my expo app on my iphone. Already is running but after few seconds on my app, I got this error  `ERROR  [TypeError: Network request failed]`

I can't see my server information and I don't understand why.
My front and my back are connected because I can see this res.json in my terminal :

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Welcome");
  res.json({message: "Bienvenue sur mon serveur !"});
});
```

But when I'm using the /firstPage (example) routes, I don't received any informations of this routes in by front.
My server and my device are running with the same wifi.
My app and my server on the port 3000.

So if someone could explain me how can I received the informations from my server ( for example the data from some sql requests )
Thanks you in advance !